# Details on the proof of: Suppose $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} X$. $X_n$ is uniformly integrable (u.i.) $\implies$ $X_n \xrightarrow{L^1} X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

I am having trouble underestanding the proof  of

**Suppose  $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} X$.**

**$X_n$ is uniformly integrable (u.i.)  $\implies$ $X_n \xrightarrow{L^1} X$**

The proof and the definitions that I am using are  in the picture below. I don't understand the omitted details on how these first 3 inequalities  were derived:  $\mathbb{E}|\varphi_K(X_n)-X_n|\le \frac{\varepsilon}{3}\tag{1}$, $\mathbb{E}|\varphi_K(X)-X|\le \frac{\varepsilon}{3}\tag{2}$ and $|\varphi_K(x)-\varphi_K(y)|\le |x-y|\tag{3}$

This is my try for (1):

To derive (1) as said in the text we need to use the uniform integrability,so I use def (5.1):  $\lim_{c \to \infty}\sup_n\mathbb{E}(|X_n|;|X_n|\ge c)=0$, which by using the definition of limit at infinity means that

$\forall \varepsilon  >0 \exists M >0$ such that for $ K>M $,$   \mathbb{E}(|X_n|;|X_n|\ge K)\le \sup_n\mathbb{E}(|X_n|;|X_n|\ge K)< \varepsilon/3 \tag{*}$

$\mathbb{E}|\varphi_K(X_n)-X_n| $

$= \mathbb{E}(|\varphi_K(X_n)-X_n|1_{|X_n|> K})+\mathbb{E}(|\varphi_K(X_n)-X_n|1_{|X_n|\le K}) $

$= \mathbb{E}(|\mp K -X_n|1_{|X_n|> K})+\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X_n|1_{|X_n|\le K})$

$\le \mathbb{E}(K 1_{|X_n|> K}) + \mathbb{E}(|X_n|1_{|X_n|> K})$

$= K \mathbb{P}(|X_n|> K) + \mathbb{E}(|X_n|1_{|X_n|> K})$

$= K \mathbb{P}(|X_n|> K) + \mathbb{E}(|X_n|;|X_n|> K)$

and this is where I am stuck it would be nice if  that "$K \mathbb{P}(|X_n|> K)$" weren't there and the second term should be with $\ge$ to use (*)(I guess that would not matter for absolutely continuous random variables, but the proof is supposed to be general , so what if  the $X_n$ are discrete? Then the expectations are sums and it should make a difference, shouldn't it? )
**How do I proceed from here? and how do I derive (2) and (3)?  In (2), I get to a similar problem upon applying equation (5.1) ,and I am clueless about (3)**

---

[image]
[image]

The definitions or results that I am using:

[image]

and notice the notation being used: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), I think you want $\varepsilon/6$ instead of $\varepsilon/3$ in your equation (*).  Then one has
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[K1_{|X_n| > K}] + \mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{|X_n| > K}] &\le \mathbb{E}[|X_n|1_{|X_n| > K}] + \mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{|X_n| > K}] \\
&= 2 \mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{|X_n| > K}] \\
&\le 2 \mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{|X_n| \ge K}] \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{3}.
\end{align*}

For (2), you can use the same idea along with the fact that $\mathbb{E}[|X|1_{|X| > K}] \rightarrow 0$ as $K \rightarrow \infty$.

For (3), this just comes from inspecting the function on a case-by-case basis.  If $|x|, |y| \le K$, then $|\phi_K(x)-\phi_K(y)| = |x-y|$.  If $x > K \ge |y|,$ $|\phi_K(x)-\phi_K(y)| = |K-y| \le |x-y|$.  You can continue this through the rest of the cases.

Comment: How do you justify $2\mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{|X_n| > K}] \le 2 \mathbb{E}[|X_n| 1_{|X_n| \ge K}] \\$?. I think this takes care of the fact that $X_n$ might be discrete, right? So my comment saying that it matters was correct, I guess.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which are the rest of the cases?

Comment: How did you obtain $|K-y| \le |x-y|$?

Comment: @some_math_guy For the first one, it's just because $1_{|X_n| > K} \le 1_{|X_n| \ge K}$.  For the second, we know $y \le |y| \le K < x$, so $|K-y| = K-y \le x-y = |x-y|$.  I think the only other cases are if $x,y \ge K$ or $x,y \le K$.